# Как проверить загрузилась ли картинка?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Есть массив url картинок . Из этого массива все картинки выводятся в dom. как проверить какая картинка не загрузилась и вывести в консоль url не загруженной картинки ?

Comment: Вы специально кривой тег изо дня в день пишите в своих сообщениях?

Comment: @Visman Нет . Какой тег ? И почему он кривой ?

Comment: Я вам уже об  этом говорил в одном из ваших вопросов. Нет в природе `javaskript`, есть только `javascript`.

Comment: @Visman Исправил. Извините

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Существуют два события, которые можно отслеживать для определения результата загрузки изображения.

```
image.onload = function(){
    //display ok
}
image.onerror = function(){
    //display error
}
```

Названия функций говорят сами за себя, но бывают ситуации когда onerror не будет вызван никогда. Это связано с тем, что часто многие cms использует общую пересылку всех ошибок 404 на свою собственную страницу и не устанавливают соответствующий код ошибки. Поэтому вы получаете ответ 200 OK (но на самом деле изображение не загружено).

Исправить подобное поведение можно проверкой размеров загруженного изображения и если ширина и высота изображения после события onload равны 0, то изображение, скорее всего, не было загружено и нужно вызвать onerror

```
image.onload=function() {
     if (this.width + this.height == 0) {
            this.onerror();
            return;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю что вариант может быть с `onerror`:

`<img src='src' onerror='console.log(this.src)'>`

Просто не знаю, как Вы их выводите. Если в `img` - тогда можно и так. Если в `svn` - то тут уже не смогу чем-то помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать для этого событие `onerror`, но в такой ситуации всегда есть вероятность, что событие сработает раньше, чем мы повесили на него обработчик.

Новомодное веяние сейчас использовать для этого дела *Promises*. К сожалению, у них пока ещё не совсем широкая [поддержка](http://caniuse.com/#search=Promises) среди браузеров. Они сделаны специально для того, чтобы удобней было работать с асинхронными событиями и вызывать всякие callback'и.

```
function getImage(url){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            resolve(url);
        };
        img.onerror = function(){
            reject(url);
        };
        img.src = url;
    });
}
```

Вот полный пример на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xgcLLsv/2/)