# Как убрать картинки которые не загрузились

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть картинки и они генерируются через ссылку. Есть картинки которые отсутствуют. Как убрать все такие картинки?

Comment: А как вообще они грузятся? Не совсем понятно, что значит "они генерируются через ссылку"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454654/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0

вот что нашёл, и пока искал наткнулся на вариант с .htaccess, 
https://javascript.ru/forum/jquery/1974-kak-proverit-zagruzheny-li-vse-kartinki-brauzerom.html в самом низу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать обработчик onerror:

```
<img src="not_found.jpg" onerror="$(this).remove();" />
```

Если картинка не будет загружена, jQuery удалит этот элемент.

Вот еще один вариант, для всех картинок:

```
$('img').error(function() { $(this).remove(); })
```

И вариант, когда надо не удалить, а заменить картинки на стандартную, например "no_photo.jpg":

```
$('img').error(function() { $(this).attr('src', 'no_photo.jpg'); })
```